# React-native app black screen when using storyboard

Tags: xcode, react-native, ipad, react-native-navigation

So basically I'm making a universal app for iPhones and iPads (also for Android but that's not the issue here) and the problem started I ran it in the iPad pro, which showed black margins in the top and bottom of the screen as if it was an older iPad.

[The margin issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8ZVO.jpg)

Some quick research revealed the following:

- According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/ipad/) to make use of the iPad Pro full display size, the target SDK must be set at least to 12.1
- Also according to Apple, I must set a storyboard instead of using a xib file

There's no problem setting the SDK version to 12.1, but when I set the launch screen to the newly created storyboard the react native app simply shows nothing except the green "loading" bar and other React-Native debug overlay stuff. It does, however, fill up the entire screen with the error message which I guess is a good thing.

But when the app finishes loading (and it does seem to run fine according to the remote debugger), there's just a black screen.

[Well, at least the errors are fullscreen I guess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asYHv.png)

I spent quite some trying to figure out what the hell is going on with no success and I couldn't find much information about either iPad pro apps on react-native or using a storyboard in react native.

I tried following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454287/app-run-gives-black-screen-in-ios-device) but couldn't get it working either...

I also tried following [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-app-icons-and-splash-screens-to-a-react-native-app-in-staging-and-production-d1dab615e7c6/) to use a storyboard in react native with no success.

I also tried a million different things until I figured I couldn't figure it out.

I have the impression that react-native won't target the new view to draw the actual JS rendered content and therefore nothing happens.

So...

How can I either get the app working on full iPad Pro display or get react-native working with the storyboard? What could I have done wrong when setting it up? Do I need to create and target a new root view for RN or something like that?

I'm going nuts trying to figure this out, any help will be appreciated. Please point out if I'm missing something incredibly obvious.

Ps. I'm not sure this matters but it might be worth noting I'm using react-native-navigation

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set Launch Screen as the storyboard seems unrelated, no? It seems like you're trying to fullscreen the window in which the RN app is contained, while the launch screen is just a splash screen.

One thing I'd check is if your AppDelegate.m (within the ios/ directory) contains a line similar to:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

I assume this is what sets the frame for the js-bundled react native app. And if the bounds are set incorrectly, it could lead to the non-fullscreen issue.

My other suggestion would be to try and see if there are any useful debugging logs in React, using the [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger). (Pretty basic suggestion, I know, but it could be useful if you haven't checked it)

P.S. I know this isn't really an answer, but StackOverflow won't let me comment to get clarification on your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Finally solved it according to my own answer

Answer (score 0):

Holy s**t after struggling for hours on this I finally solved the issue following this:

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4580#issuecomment-482669978

It was something to do with react-native-navigation indeed.

I couldn't believe when it actually worked!

Hopefully this helps somebody save some time in the future